# Is it possible to create tree like structure of widgets that are in root window tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Is it possible to create tree like structure of widgets that are in root window tkinter.Like in Windows Operating System in command prompt if we type tree followed by a folder name it displays files and folder inside it.Is it possible to create likewise in tkinter.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGr9k.png)

Comment: You are looking for [tree](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html)

Comment: I had uploaded a image in my question.Is it possible to do that likewise in tkinter?

Comment: Didn't the image at the given link explain this?